# Cross Account SNS Lambda Subscription using CDK

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-cdk

I have 2 AWS CDK applications running in separate AWS accounts, and I'm trying to add CDK to get a lambda in one AWS account to subscribe to notifications in the other AWS account.

I tried adding the subscription in the lambda account, but this didn't work, since the SNS account doesn't grant permissions.

CDK in the SNS account:

```
val myTopic = Topic(this, "my-topic-id", TopicProps.builder()
            .displayName("topicName")
            .topicName("topicName")
            .build())
```

CDK in the Lambda account:

```
val myLambda = Function(...)

val crossAccountTopic = Topic.fromTopicArn(this, "topic-id", "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountId>:topicName")

crossAccountTopic.addSubscription(LambdaSubscription(myLambda))
```

Has anyone tried something like this? Is there a way to grant access purely with changes to CDK in both accounts? Or is a manual action required? There may be a way to do this by granting access through IAM roles, so I will investigate this further.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can grant access in both accounts through CDK. First, you must grant access in the providing account, and deploy the CDK/cloudformation stack. Then you can grant access in the client account.

CDK in the SNS account:

```
val myTopic = Topic(this, "my-topic-id", TopicProps.builder()
        .displayName("topicName")
        .topicName("topicName")
        .build())
PolicyStatement snsAccessPolicy = PolicyStatement.Builder.create()
            .principals(listOf(AccountPrincipal("123456346")))
            .actions(Arrays.asList("SNS:Subscribe"))
            .resources(Arrays.asList(myTopic.getTopicArn()))
            .build();
myTopic.addToResourcePolicy(snsAccessPolicy);
```

CDK in the Lambda account:

```
val myLambda = Function(...)

val crossAccountTopic = Topic.fromTopicArn(this, "topic-id", "arn:aws:sns:<region>:<accountId>:topicName")

crossAccountTopic.addSubscription(LambdaSubscription(myLambda))
```

Note that the `AccountPrinciple` declared in the `PolicyStatement` of the SNS account refers to the **AWS account ID** of the subscribing **Lambda account**. Intuitively, the SNS account is granting access to the Lambda account, so the SNS account policy needs to grant the Lambda account access.

Comment: What is AccountPrinciple? Is it the account ID of Lambda?

Comment: Yup! It's the account ID of the Lambda

Comment: Can we add multiple account IDs since SNS topic can be consumed by multiple consumers?

Comment: Also, we should be including publisher permission for the resource publishing message to sns right?

Comment: @Ronnie Yes, you can add multiple subscribers to an SNS topic in CDK. And yes, if you want to publish to a topic you can set that up too. I’d recommend posting a separate question if you have questions about setting up a publisher to a topic with CDK